# Jquery: Prevent window scrolling after link is clicked

Tags: jquery

I have 2 links that hide present different information to the users on the main page. If one link is clicked, the new info appears on screen. Problem is, when I click on any of the links, the window is taken back to the top of the page. I would like to prevent this behavior as it is annoying.

Here is the code for the links

```
<div align="right" id="ajaxIncomingMail"><a href="#" class="incomingMail">Incoming Mail</a></div><div id="ajaxOutgoingMail"><h5><a href="#" class="outgoingMail">Outgoing Mail</a></h5></div>
```

and here is the code for the jquery:

```
        $(function(){
      $("a.incomingMail").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#ajaxMailShowContentOutbox").hide();
            $("#ajaxMailShowContentInbox").fadeIn("slow");
        });

        $("a.outgoingMail").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#ajaxMailShowContentInbox").hide();
            $("#ajaxMailShowContentOutbox").fadeIn("slow");
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Here I am using preventDefault() and it's still not working!? I also tried return false, but that didn't work also. I don't know if it matters, but the info that is presented is pulled with php from the db. How can I make the scrolling stop when I click on the link??

Comment: e.preventDefault() should do it. Is the page scrolling to the top, or is it scrolling due to the fact that the content in the page is changing?

Comment: I agree with Kevin Gurney -- he probably needs to use .live(), if the links are in fact being added to the page after the DOM has loaded and the javascript has already executed.

Comment: partkyle, the scrolling is due to the fact that the content on the page is changing. And no, the links themselves don't change - it's only the content that changes, but not the links.

Comment: Is your issue solved, have a look on this link and let me know. http://jsfiddle.net/tsegay/fWyxM/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Shouldn't the `return false;` be within the actual jQuery click event and not outside it?

**edit**

```
    $(function(){
  $("a.incomingMail").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#ajaxMailShowContentOutbox").hide();
        $("#ajaxMailShowContentInbox").fadeIn("slow");
        return false;
    });

    $("a.outgoingMail").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#ajaxMailShowContentInbox").hide();
        $("#ajaxMailShowContentOutbox").fadeIn("slow");
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: I have the returns within the cilck event, but I think it has something to do with how I am manipulating my divs and classes.

Comment: care to show me how? I have always interpreting the above code as: .click(function(){ //inside click event right? return false; }); //outside click function now

Comment: my fault. Yes, in my original post I was outside the click function. I corrected it though. Thanks. lol, silly me!

Answer (score 5):

you might have href='#' in the a tag, change it to href='###' and it should stop scrolling.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try:

```
$("a.incomingMail").live("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#ajaxMailShowContentOutbox").hide();
    $("#ajaxMailShowContentInbox").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

and

```
$("a.outgoingMail").live("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#ajaxMailShowContentInbox").hide();
    $("#ajaxMailShowContentOutbox").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

instead of .click if your info is being pulled from a database, because binding the click event handler to your links with .click() will **only apply the event handler to elements already loaded on the page** and **not elements that are being loaded later** from your database.

Comment: Still not working : ( What version of jQuery do I need in order to use live() ??

Comment: Just checked: I have jQuery V1.4.1 so that's shouldn't be the problem. I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Perhaps you could try wrapping your code in $(document).ready(function() {//Code goes in here});? I'm not really sure if that will make any difference though.

Comment: I moved the block of code from the header and placed it beneath the code being generated and used the $(document).ready as you suggested...no luck. I bet it's going to turn out to be something simple. Ooh the fun!

Comment: You might want to try testing out your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/cGKcM/. I wrapped your code in $(document).ready(function() {}); like I mentioned above also just to let you know and I set JSFiddle to use JQuery 1.5.

Comment: It's weird. I modified my code to not pull info from db and just use static content - same problem.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to make a JSFiddle using static content?

Comment: Ok, this is as close as I can get it. http://jsfiddle.net/cGKcM/11/ when you scroll down the page, then click on incomingMail or outgoingmail, the content will show, but the window will scroll back up to the top

Comment: That is sort of strange. It is sort of difficult to tell that it is scrolling up in JSFiddle though. Maybe you could have the content appear in a pop up box or something rather than just filling it in where the previous content was when you click on outgoing or incoming mail?

Comment: I'm not really sure if this could a problem but you might want to try taking out the <body> tags and <a href> tags in your paragraphs. They may be causing the scrolling issue because they are not properly closed and what not.

Comment: that's a possible solution, but I don't want to overdo it with popups. I already have other popups for other features.

Comment: Ok, that is fine, but did you read my other suggestion about removing the various html tags that you have in your paragraphs which could possibly be causing issues?

Comment: No, I didn't see that suggestion. I ll take your suggestion and just start with a basic div, test it out, build on it, repeat. It's worth a shot. I ll post my findings when I am done.